# Find Memory Usage Peaks

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, runtime

I am having an issue with my java game, the memory being used by it is jumping a lot. I have this method created to find how much memory is being used:

```
public String readable(long bytes, boolean si) {
    int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if (bytes < unit) {
        return bytes + " B";
    }
    int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
    String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp - 1) + (si ? "" : "i");
    return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
}

readable(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory(), true)
```

It starts off at 200mb initially, them jumps to 600m then progressively increases. How would I monitor why this is happening and look for memory leaks that cause this? Is there a plugin on eclipse that I can install to view memory usage and resources?

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should not check this. The better way of doing this would be to see the heap dump. If you are using eclipse, you can download MAT [a link](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)!

Answer (score 0):

`totalMemory` counts both reachable and unreachable objects. Interpreting the behavior of this quantity requires a lot of understanding of garbage collection.

I suggest you use VisualVM instead. Install the VisualGC plugin and watch your application's memory, divided into GC generations, shrink and grow dynamically.